# Rails + Spree: How do I create a Taxonomy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I looked at this: http://api.spreecommerce.com/v1/taxonomies/#creating-a-taxonomy

But I don't understand when they say make a POST to /api/taxonomies. How would I do that? Is there no way in the admin section to create a taxonomy/category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for API, you can create from admin panel, just navigate to Configuration > Taxonomies. In case you wonder what the hell is the difference between `Taxon` and `Taxonomy` - basically, they are the same thing, `Taxonomy` is a root `Taxon` (i.e. `Taxon` without `parent`). There are of course differences, but they are out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomies can also be created through the administration interface.  Try browsing to /admin/taxonomies under your store root.